# How do I access the actual storage of an Android device with my MAUI App?

Tags: c#, android, .net, local-storage, maui

I am making an audio player app with MAUI (.Net-8.0) and obviously need to access the device's folders. For example, Android has /Internal storage/Music/ folder and I want to access the .mp3 files in it.

As far as I know, I need to ask for permissions to read the device's files. So in AndroidManifest.xml, under permissions, I checked the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.Then in the MainPage.xaml.cs I wrote:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
    }

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        musicPath = GetMusicPath();
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: not granted  permission
    }
}

public string GetMusicPath()
{
    return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
}
```

If I Debug.WriteLine(musicPath) i get "data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/files/Music", which I'm assuming is not what I'm looking for because I can't find my files (which I have in "/Internal storage/Music/"). I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but me and my friend have spent more than 3 days on this and can't seem to find anything about it on the internet.

Comment: The permissions you mentioned are only needed fir Android 12- devices. But even if you have these permissions you will not be able to list those Music files on those devices if they are not created by your app.

Comment: Environment. has other members. The ide will show them i think. Try them all.

Comment: `Android has /Internal storage/Music/` No. Android does not have that. You probably see that in some obscure file manager app. Android has external storage location `/storage/emulated/0/Music`.

Comment: `and can't seem to find anything about it on the internet` If you would just take the time to read some stackoverflow pages tagged `android` ..

Comment: You can’t just read system folders.  You will need to use the Android media APIs to access that content

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455935/how-do-i-get-data-about-all-audio-files-in-the-users-device-using-xamarin-andr